# how to create admin user on dynamodb using cdk typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, devops, aws-cdk

```js
const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'MyTable', {
   partitionKey: {
         name: 'customer_id', 
           type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING 
        },
   sortKey:{
         name:"orderId",
         type:dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING
       }});
```

I had created table on aws-dynamodb using cdk but, I want to make a table with admin user.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not have the concept of database users, unlike, say, postgres.  Instead, access is controlled with [IAM user or role credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/authentication-and-access-control.html).

If you have a lambda function that will be making dynamo requests, for instance, you need to give the proper permissions to the lambda's role.  The CDK makes this super-easy:

```js
// give the lambda read-write permissions
table.grantReadWriteData(myLambdaFunction);
```

Comment: You are welcome!  Consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it was helpful.